# How to implement 17 host with agora io in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io

I've tried the agora flutter quick start and it's really good.

But agora said it can have 17 host at a channel. how to implement it the best practice?

Here's the layout from sample:

```
Widget _viewRows() {
final views = _getRenderViews();
switch (views.length) {
  case 1:
    return Container(
        child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[_videoView(views[0])],
    ));
  case 2:
    return Container(
        child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _expandedVideoRow([views[0]]),
        _expandedVideoRow([views[1]])
      ],
    ));
  case 3:
    return Container(
        child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(0, 2)),
        _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(2, 3))
      ],
    ));
  case 4:
    return Container(
        child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(0, 2)),
        _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(2, 4))
      ],
    ));
  default:
}
return Container();
```

}

I'd like to add up to 13 more views to optimize video conference capability from agora.. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Agora video sdk supports up to 7 people at the same time (Video support for up to 25 people is under development).

And if you wanted to add more than 4 people to your stream you can simply extend the the switch case like

```
case 5:
return Container(
    child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(0, 2)),
    _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(2, 4)),
    _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(4, 5))
  ],
));
case 6:
return Container(
    child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(0, 2)),
    _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(2, 4)),
    _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(4, 6))
  ],
));
case 7:
return Container(
    child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(0, 2)),
    _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(2, 4)),
    _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(4, 6)),
    _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(6, 7)),
  ],
));
```

You can also create your own interface where 'views' are not added in rows and columns but using a stack or any other widget of your choice.

Comment: For a higher scaling I will suggest you to use a for loop with _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(i, i+2)) and _expandedVideoRow(views.sublist(i, i+1)),